# Is a single thread in nodejs and web browser same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

The concept of single-thread and event-loop and callback in web browser is same with that of node.js ??

And if so, is it because v8 use that concept in doing work(both chrome and node.js use v8)?

Was v8 designed like that?

Comment: It's not specific to V8. Every JS engine behaves like that.

Comment: @estus I think Rhino had Java's multithreading model, but it was weird indeed. Yes, most standalone JS implementations use the same concurrency model as in browsers.

Answer (score 5):

The specified behaviour of JS in [ECMA-262](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) defines JS evaluation in terms of an "[Agent](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#agent)" which is essentially an abstracted term for a thread. The JS engines of all major browsers follow this specification, and obviously Node.js uses the same engine as Chromium.

The execution context stack, which (in simplified terms) handles function calls, is scoped to agents, so you can't really work with JS in a multi-threaded environment.

This is why Web Workers cannot pass objects around, and instead use [structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)s.

The concept of the event loop is also defined in the ECMA-262, with the combined behaviour of [RunJobs()](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runjobs) and [Jobs and Job Queues](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues). Job queues are also scoped to agents, so they cannot handle multi-threaded environments.

Promises are currently the only thing defined in ECMA-262 that use the job queue (Promise handlers always run in a new tick), but Node.js and browsers make heavy use of the event loop for IO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean, (1) JS Engine use a thread which is called Agent. (2) they do not use multi-thread (3) Node.js and Browswer both like to use event loop for I/O.. right?

Comment: @ByeonginYoon pretty much. If you want to learn a bit more, MDN has a nice summary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Have Node introduced or is about to introduce new concepts not present in browser implementations? I am watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SULk05iqGIw and I see a whole bunch of functions as well as structures that seem to be unique to Node, especially in v10 and later versions currently in development. For example, things like Workers — is it the same as Web Worker in browsers? — that use separate event loops. More broadly, does Node move in direction when the code will run on Node and in browser differently, or becomes incompatible?